# Restriction to the total angular momentum of two identical particles with spin 1

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, identical-particles

I've been asked if there is any aditional restriction to obtain the possible values of the total angular momentum J by considering that the 2 particles of spin S=1 are identical.
If they are not identical the total angular momentum J can take the 2,1,0 values , we are considering that the orbital angular momentum L is 0.
Thanks

Comment: you need to take into account that since the particles are not fermions, they do not obey the Pauli exclusion principle and hence different from the case of electrons.

Comment: But the particles were also bosons when we assume them to be "not identical".

Comment: not identical doesn't imply that the particles are bosons.

Comment: Whether they are identical or not does not change the angular momentum restrictions.

Comment: So the posibles values of the total angular momentum $J$ are still being 0,1,2? I thought it could have something related to the simetry or antysimetry. Thanks

Comment: @BruceLee you´re right, but the fact that they have spin=1 yes